# How to Convert an image in PNG format to GIF Format

Tags: image, base64, png, gif

I need to convert a PNG image Base 64 to GIF Base 64 format in JavaScript or C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use ffmpeg with nodejs, you could spawn an ffmpeg process inside of node.js which will allow you to convert apng/animated-webp to an animated gif. Although this solution is not purely a node.js solution, it can be combined with node.js and used in any environment which node.js can function in.

**[Edit]**

According to the status of [this ffmpeg ticket](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/ticket/4907), you can not decode animated WEBP images with ffmpeg.

Using ffmpeg you can convert apng files to .gif files.

I have provided an example script which assumes that you have ffmpeg installed and configured in your PATH environment variable.

The usage of this function is fairly simple. Just replace "/path/to/file" with where your file is located (i.e. "./input.apng") and it will output a file named: "input.apng.gif" in the same directory.

```js
var gifLocation = await convertToGif("/path/to/file")
.catch((err) =>
{
    console.error("[Error]", err);
});

if (gifLocation)
    console.log("Location:", gifLocation);
```

Here's a working script (without the path to a file)

```js
const { exec } = require('child_process');
const fs = require("fs");

async function convertToGif(inputFile)
{
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)
    {
        if (!fs.existsSync(inputFile))
        {
            console.error("[ffmpeg] File doesn't exist");
            reject(false);
            return;
        }

        const ls = exec(`ffmpeg -i "${inputFile}" -f gif "${inputFile}.gif"`, function (error, stdout, stderr)
        {
            if (error)
            {
                console.log(error.stack);
                console.log('[ffmpeg] Error code: '+error.code);
                console.log('[ffmpeg] Signal received: '+error.signal);
            }
            /*console.log('[ffmpeg] Child Process STDOUT: '+stdout);
            console.log('[ffmpeg] Child Process STDERR: '+stderr);*/
        });
    
        ls.on('exit', function (code)
        {
            //console.log('[ffmpeg] Child process exited with exit code ' + code);
            if (code != 0)
            {
                reject(false);
            }
            else
            {
                resolve(`${inputFile}.gif`);
            }
        });
    });
}

async function run()
{
    var gifLocation = await convertToGif("/path/to/file")
    .catch((err) =>
    {
        console.error("[Error]", err);
    });

    if (gifLocation)
        console.log("Location:", gifLocation);
}

run();
```

Comment: I updated my post with more information including code showing how to spawn an ffmpeg process in node.js